# Maintaining a login and session for an external API PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, api, session, soap

I have an API provided by a third party provider which  can be used for creating virtual money , creating gift cards etc.The API has resources like

```
Creating customers
Transfer of funds between customers
Crediting virtual money to customers account
Debiting virtual money from customers account etc..
```

To APIs are in SOAP and I am sending soap request to access the resources.To use any of the resources in the API , I have to login using the login API they provided.Once I login they sent back a sessionID which has a validity of 2 minutes and it will expire after that.I can keep alive the session using the Keepalive api which will keep the session alive for another 2 minutes.

When ever I call any of the resources say create customer,I have to sent the sessionID along with that.

The problem is Im not able to maintain the session and its failing.Im using codeigniter.The login I have currently kept is as follows

```
class Wallet
{
    function __construct()
    {

        $this->ci =& get_instance();
        $this->ci->load->model('merchant_model');

        define("UID",     "test");
        define("PWD",    "34rf3a4557510c82d47d0ac1a5244c4eba0762b3");
        define("API_ENDPOINT", "http://uat-api.*******.in/services/smp");
        define("PRODUCT_CODE", "24");
        $SessionID = $this->keepAliveLib();
        define("SessionID",$SessionID);
    }
    function keepAliveLib()
    {
       $SessionID = $this->ci->merchant_model->updateWalletSession();
       if($SessionID)
       {
            return $SessionID;
       } else {
           return $this->login();
       }
    }
function login()                                                                                    
    {
        $soap_do = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_URL,API_ENDPOINT);
        curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
        curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
        curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,false);
        curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POST,true);            
        curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"<?xml version='1.1'?>
        <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:sas='http://uat-api.******.in/services/simulator'>
        <SOAP-ENV:Body>
            <sas:Login>
            <Username>".UID."</Username>
            <Password>".PWD."</Password>
            </sas:Login>
        </SOAP-ENV:Body>
        </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>");
        $response = curl_exec($soap_do);
        $xml = simplexml_load_string($response, NULL, NULL, "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
        $ns = $xml->getNamespaces(true);
        $soap = $xml->children($ns['SOAP-ENV']);
        $res = $soap->Body->children($ns['ns1']);
        foreach ($xml->xpath('/SOAP-ENV:Envelope/SOAP-ENV:Body/ns1:LoginResponse/return') as $item) 
        {
          $response =  (array) $item;
        }
        $res = $this->ci->merchant_model->insertNewWalletSession($response);
        if($res)
        {
            return $response['SessionID'];
        }
    }
    //Other function follows
```

This is a library,

1. whenever this library is loaded,keepAliveLib() function is triggered
   2.The keepAliveLib() function will check in the database for any session IDs which is not older that 2minutes.The piece of code is

   $this->merchant->select('SessionID, creationTime');
           $query = $this->merchant->get($this->wallet_keepalive_sessions_table);
           $res = $query->result_array();
           foreach($query->result() as $row)
           {
               $SessionID          = $row->SessionID;
               $creationTime   = $row->creationTime;
           }

   ```
       if( strtotime($creationTime) > strtotime("-2 minutes"))
       {
           $data['creationTime'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
           $this->merchant->where('SessionID', $SessionID);
           $this->merchant->update($this->wallet_keepalive_sessions_table, $data);
           return $SessionID;
       } else{
           return 0;
       }
   ```

If there is any sessionID older than 2 minute it will return null otherwise sent a sessionID back which is alive and set this sessionID in the constructor as a contstant,otherwise it will call the login API and login to the api and save the sessionID in the database.

This is the whole process.But this doesnt seems to work fine.

When some functions are called its going with an invalid session or blank session.

Can someone provide me a standard practice on how a session can be maintained over an API which has a time out?

PLease help out.

Comment: Rather than compare your timestamps in php it might be better to make it another where clause in your query

Comment: Also in your return im the function, 0 and null are not the same thing. With phps loose type i would be more explicit and make sure your if statements are not causing the problem. Make sure you do a comparison for null.